in a Flutter application where custom plugin A's native code needs to access a private framework (xxx.framework) from custom plugin B
In a Flutter application, the native code of custom plugin A needs to reference the private xxx.framework framework introduced in custom plugin B. Attempts to add dependencies in A's pubspec.yaml configuration or to add vendored_frameworks in a_xxx.podspec dependency library have both failed. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
The example project address: https://github.com/106271/multi_custom_plugin
compiler success.
